# How to set up Colors for Test Output when Using Mocha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mocha.js, ansi-escape

I was using gem `turn` to format ANSI color output for tests, which worked great.

Then I discovered that it doesn't work with mocha. Is there a way to get them to work together? How do you create color output when working with mocha?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem redgreen works with Mocha and provides nice color output for tests.

Here's how to get it to work: [In rails is it possible to get colour highlighting for the rake test command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992083/in-rails-is-it-possible-to-get-colour-highlighting-for-the-rake-test-command/3992396#3992396)