# Test unit results in color using console but not tmux unless --use-color is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit, tmux

If I create a new Rails (3.2.12) app. Add the `test-unit` gem to my development, test group, and then scaffolded resource. When I run the tests from the Mac console.app, I get color output.

```
bundle exec rake test
```

When I create a tmux session (in console.app) for the app and run the exact same command. I don't get color output. However if I pass the "--use-color" switch, then I do get color output for the tests in tmux.

```
bundle exec rake test TESTOPTS="--use-color"
```

I'm setting 256 colors in my `tmux.config` with `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`. Any idea why I don't get color in tmux when I run the rake task without the TESTOPTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that *test-unit* guesses whether the terminal supports color by (mainly) looking at the TERM environment variable. Unfortunately, `screen-256color` does not satisfy the [checks that it makes](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/2.5.4/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb#L465).

It might be reasonable to ask that its recognition of `screen` be extended to include `screen-256color`, also.

I think you can drop some entries in a configuration file to supply default arguments. The first of `test-unit.yml` (in the current directory) or `~/.test-unit.yml` (a “hidden” file in your home directory) will be loaded:

```
runner: console
console_options:
  arguments: --use-color=yes
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to get the configuration file to work when named `.test-unit.yml`. I read in test-unit help doc (http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/en/Test/Unit.html#label-Configuration+file) that it needed to be named `test-unit.yml` (without the period - so I guess it can't be a hidden file :().

Comment: Right, it only checks for the non-hidden version in the current directory, the hidden one is read from your home directory (and only if the non-hidden one does not exist in the current directory).